# How can I edit remove excessive exact lines from expect script?

Tags: tcl, expect

I have created an expect script using expect, and I realize that the expect -exact are constructed to match lines contain lots of unnecesary output. For example when I execute a postgresql restore command all the psql output gets included in the expect -exact line.

What other syntax can be used to trim the expect -exact lines? Can they be removed in some cases?

Comment: Did you mean that you created it using “autoexpect”?

Answer (score 0):

Tools that generate scripts by watching activity in a session are definitely prone to thinking far too much is significant. They simply do not understand what matters. Typically, the way to get rid of the unnecessarily-expected pieces is to just remove them with a text editor. The places to watch out for are where you're coming up to a `send` (or `exp_send`; there's a few variations); it's a good idea to always have an `expect` of *something* before a `send`, but what that should be needs some smarts on your part.

---

Later on, you may want to write scripts that can handle multiple conditions under which to take action by `expect`ing several things at once. That's when you write things like this:

```
expect {
   "abc" {
      send "foo\r"
   }
   "def" {
      send "bar\r"
   }
}
```

There's a lot more complexity to automating access to an application than there appears to be at first because applications often *are* more complex than they appear to be at first.